# Mongodb $set not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update the nested document. The query is returning the correct document, but the property isn't being updated.

Model:

```
{
     _id: '560b072434b72aa4050fff9f',
     trips: [
       {
          tripId: '561581ef9387780e76469e96',
          startDate: "2015-11-17T06:00:00.000Z",
          endDate: "2015-11-18T06:00:00.000Z"
       },{
          tripId: '5617d1bb1d42c4da90d3bdea',
          startDate: "2015-10-17T06:00:00.000Z",
          endDate: "2015-10-18T06:00:00.000Z"
       }
     ],
}
```

Query:

```
UserData.update(
      { '_id': req.query._id, 'trips.tripId': req.query.tripId },
      { '$set': { 'trips.$.startDate' : req.query.newStartDate,
                  'trips.$.endDate' : req.query.newEndDate} },
      { 'multi': true },
      function(e, doc){
           console.log(doc);
      }
 );
```

Schema:

```
var userDataSchema = {
  name: String,
  trips: Array
};
```

Comment: Take a look at [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

Comment: Why `{ 'multi': true }`? aren't you trying to update only one document, since you specify the `_id`?

Comment: Yeah, I had read in another SO article that you had to have 'multi' set to true. I've tried $elemMatch and removing multi true and it's still not updating. As I stated, the correct record is getting pulled and the trips that don't have matching ids are not being returned -- it's just not updating the record at all `{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }`.

Comment: Show your schema you have defined. Noting that you have a numeric `_id` value here and mongoose requires special handling if you override the default `ObjectId` that you are likely missing. Note that the result confirms that nothing is being matched, so there is a problem with the input and the schema definition is a likely cause.

Comment: @BlakesSeven That's my fault. I tried to simplify for adding it on here. I've updated the schema and _id field to what they are in the collection. Additionally, it finds a match when I use the query string: `db.userData.find({'_id': req.query._id, 'trips.tripId': req.query.tripId})`

Comment: Correction: That query does not work on the server. It works in the mongo shell when I do `db.userData.find( { '_id': ObjectId('560b072434b72aa4050fff9f') , 'trips.tripId' : ObjectId('561581ef9387780e76469e96') } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BlakesSeven led me to the answer. I added:

`var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

before my app.route in server.js, installed mongodb using npm, then changed

`{ '_id': req.query._id, 'trips.tripId': req.query.tripId },`

to

`{ '_id': ObjectId(req.query._id), 'trips.tripId': ObjectId(req.query.tripId) },`.

Everything updates as it should now. Thanks Blakes Seven!